# What is "one" in leave-one-out cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, information-theory

Lets say I have $x_{ij} \sim Bernoulli(p_j)$ and $d_j = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} \sim Binomial(n, p_j)$ I could do binomial logistic regression by regressing the logit of $p_j$s on some predictors. If I was then interested in doing some cross validation like LOOCV, what is the difference in leaving out one $x_{ij}$, computing the $d_j$s, and fitting, vs leaving out one of the $d_j$s?

Maybe more concretely:
Consider data

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df <- expand.grid(p=1:10, rep=1:12) %>% 
  mutate(x = rbinom(10*12,1,prob=plogis(-2 + 0.3*p)))

df_grouped <- df %>% group_by(p) %>% summarize(d = sum(x), n=length(x))
```

I can then either do

```
glm(x ~ p, data=df, family="binomial")
```

or

```
glm(cbind(d,n-d) ~ p, data=df_grouped, family="binomial")
```

Now if I am interested in doing leave one out cross validation what is the difference in leaving out a row in `df`, fitting the model, and computing statistics (repeat for all rows) VS leaving out a row in `df_grouped`, fitting the model, and computing statistics?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your setup. Could you perhaps write it down more fully using model equations? Since if the dependent variable is $x_{ij}$, why would you want to leave $d_j$ out?

Comment: I don't understand the confusion: my question is if I am doing LOOCV in a binomial regression setting what is the experimental unit which I need to "leave out", a single observation (ie $x_{ij}$) or a whole group (ie $d_j$) or will the cross validated statistics be equivalent?

Comment: I do not understand the idea of involving $d_j$ in the business of cross validation. If you want to cross-validate a logistic regression where $x_{ij}$ is the dependent variable, $d_j$ plays no role. There is no way you can leave $d_j$ out as it is not part of the model. On the other hand, perhaps I do not understand your model. Why do you say *leaving out one $x_{ij}$, computing the $d_j$s, and fitting*? You do not need to compute $d_j$s for fitting the logistic regression.

Comment: $x_{ij}$ and $d_j$ are both the dependent variable; one is grouped. In R this would be differences between something like `glm( x ~ ..., family="binomial")` vs `glm(cbind(d, n-d) ~ ...,family="binomial")`

Comment: @RichardHardy see my updated question

Comment: Thanks, that is easier to follow. I do not use pipe logic myself, but I think I now get what you are doing. Do not have an answer, though. I guess it depends on how `glm` works in the second case. I wonder what model that is.

Comment: I was just trying to quickly make a reproducible example to explain myself better

Comment: why does it depend on glm? the 2nd way does binomial regression, it results in same estimates for the coefficients. My question to me seems more about how cross validation works

Comment: If I understand this correctly, what is called p in your code is *not* what is called $p_j$ in the introduction, right?

Comment: @bdeonovic, I am just saying I do not understand what `glm` does in the second case. I do not understand what the underlying model is and what estimator is used. I took a quick look at the help files and could not find a description of your second case there (while I did find the first case). (But I did not look very hard; it was late, and I went to sleep.) Have you seen your second case described anywhere in the help files of `glm` or elsewhere?

Comment: @RichardHardy see point 3 under details here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/family.html

Comment: @ChristianHennig correct sorry the p in code does not correspond to $p_j$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I think. First consideration: The answer should depend on what you actually want to predict. If the $x_{ij}$ (or rather their associated predictors) come in one by one and you're interested in the prediction quality you get for every single one of these, using all individual observations you already have, leave out one $x_{ij}$ row at a time. If a whole bunch of observations (or a $d_j$) at the same predictor position (let me call that $z_j$) comes in at once and you want to predict that, leave out a $(z_j,d_j)$. In fact I can also imagine an intermediate situation where, say, $d_j$ comes in for a set of, say, 10 $x_{ij}$ at a time, but you may already have other observations at the same $z_j$ (the way you formulated it it looked like $d_j$ referred to *all* observations with the same $z_j$, but this is not necessary in my view), then I'd leave out one "observational set" at a time.

The difference between these is that if you have, say, 100 individual $x_{ij}$ in sets of 10 each, obviously in the first version you have 99 observations to predict the 100th one, in the second version you have only 90 observations to predict a $d_j$, and if the $z_j$ are all different for different $d_j$, you won't have *any* observation at the same $z_j$ (although as I said, this isn't necessarily always so), so chances are you'll be slightly worse off than in the first version.

Second consideration: When doing the actual prediction of new data, you will use all 100 observations that you already have in the case above, and it is actually equivalent predicting a new $x_{ij}$ by $\hat x_{ij}$, say, or $d_j$ by $n\hat x_{ij}$. As the first LOO-CV version predicts from 99 observations and the second one from 90, the first one will have a smaller bias (it might have a larger variance but I don't think that'll trump the bias here, I may be wrong though). For this reason arguably you could use version 1 for both cases.

On the other hand, if indeed you want to predict $d_j$ and all $d_j$ indeed come with different, i.e., new $z_j$, it may be more realistic to use the second LOO-CV version in which no observations with the same $z_j$ are used for prediction (it may improve prediction quality to have such observations already, and if this is not the real situation, that may lead to an optimistic estimate of the prediction error).

If your aim is comparing models rather than assessing the final prediction error, I expect hardly any difference between the two approaches (the second version may be problematic if numbers of observations are critically low).

Comment: This was helpful, i will think on it